# How can I do a complete test of credit card processing with PayPal's PayFlowPro?

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I've already posted this on PayPal's x.com developer forum, but have always gotten fantastic results here, so I figured it couldn't hurt to ask...

I've inherited a site from a developer who's no longer with the company. All I was given was the live URL that the PHP transaction submits to (https://payflowpro.paypal.com) and the username and password that need to be sent through with the transaction.

However, we need to make some changes to our code and I definitely don't want to do it live. I did find that there's a test URL that can be used (https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com) but have been unable to find any information in the pdf guide that indicates whether there's a test username and password to use, or whether you send through your live account credentials with the dummy credit card numbers.

I'm also unable to determine if there's a test version of the PayPal Manager app that would allow me to see the transactions as they would appear to our client.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you get an error message when you try a test?

Comment: No; we didn't want to try using the test URL until we knew where it was going and how we could see the resultant transaction. I did get a response from someone on the x.com forum. Apparently there's no such thing as a test account for PayFlowPro - you need a live merchant account; any transactions submitted to the test URL show up under a Test category in the live account.

Comment: GTK that the vendor keeps there docs up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I've used payflowpro in the past.  as long as you are sending to the test link you should be fine.  and yes, there are test credit card numbers.   visa is 4111-1111-1111-1111 any expry.  I'm sure the process has been updated in the recent years.

have you tried this link?  It looks like it may have some useful info.

http://wiki.avectra.com/PayFlow_Pro

**edit:**
I see you don't need the test card numbers but check that link I think it has the information you are after.
if not I found this page as well https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/How-to-use-PayPal/Testing-my-web-sites-PayPal-payment-process/m-p/16326#M6000

Comment: Thanks. I know there are test credit card numbers; I'm talking about the account credentials you send through with the backend transaction so it knows what vender account the transaction is coming from. The wiki page doesn't really have any recent information; the link to the paypal site is no longer correct.

Comment: @EmmyS Paypal's site makes reference to setting up an account at sandbox.paypal.com https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services/Testing-pay-palbutton-on-my-website/m-p/51439#M512

Comment: The sandbox account is for different payment solutions; it doesn't include PayFlowPro.

Comment: I wish my brain was working better....I had to go through this whole process with payflowpro a few years ago... I know there was some 'magic' account.  I'll add it out here once I remember.

Comment: Doug, I get the feeling, from what I've been reading on the x.com site, that the process has changed recently.

Comment: I think Your right.  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1126-Testing-Credit-Card-Transactions-In-Payflow-Pro-Thanks-Dan-Vega-.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is the description how to setup the test Payflow account (https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/pp_integrations_preston/testing-paypal-payflow-gateway).

Just one more note: if you wish to test API calls directly you need Payflow Pro instead of Payflow Link as with Payflow Link you are only limited to the Checkout Template Page, and not able to do any API call programmatically. This is good for testing, but in production you can still use Payflow Link.